# Rabbit Listener execute consumer always when Rabbitmq node is down or stop

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

when RabbitMq server available am producing some messages to Rabbitmq Exchange and consuming that messages bases on Queuename with Rabbit Listener.but when no messages in queue iam getting always

My code is like below

```
<bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
        <property name="prefetchCount" value="10"/>
        <property name="defaultRequeueRejected" value="false"/>
</bean>
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="5" prefetch="10" acknowledge="auto" idle-event-interval="500000000000000">
     <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" queue-names="queue.email" />
     <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" queue-names="queue.sms" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

I am expecting to getting no exception while RabbitMq node is stopped

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException: Auto recovery connection is not currently open
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.isOpen(SimpleConnection.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.isOpen(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1500(CachingConnectionFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1333)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help us to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

Set `autoRecoveryEnabled` to `false` if you are configuring the underlying connection factory yourself.

See [Configuring the Underlying Client Connection Factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#connection-factory).

> **NOTE** The 4.0.x client enables automatic recovery by default; while compatible with this feature, Spring AMQP has its own recovery mechanisms and the client recovery feature generally isn’t needed. It is recommended to disable amqp-client automatic recovery, to avoid getting `AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException`s when the broker is available, but the connection has not yet recovered. You may notice this exception, for example, when a RetryTemplate is configured in a RabbitTemplate, even when failing over to another broker in a cluster. Since the auto recovering connection recovers on a timer, the connection may be recovered faster using Spring AMQP’s recovery mechanisms. **Starting with version 1.7.1, Spring AMQP disables it unless you explicitly create your own RabbitMQ connection factory and provide it to the CachingConnectionFactory**. RabbitMQ ConnectionFactory instances created by the RabbitConnectionFactoryBean will also have the option disabled by default.

Comment: property autoRecoveryEnabled is not available in SimpleListenerContainer factory.i did  check with CachingConnectionFactory also.property autoStartup is available.can u plse add that configuration it is so helpful.

Comment: We don't want to encourage setting that property; as I said, unless you are using 1.7.0 the property is false by default unless you inject a com.rabbitmq connection factory (if you are using 1.7.0, you should upgrade to 1.7.5), 
If you are injecting a com.rabbitmq connection factory, you should set its property to false.